# Is there any way to obtain all in-app purchase information of users in the current application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I need to judge whether the current user can try the subscription for free. The button needs to be changed

If I get the receiver that the user has purchased, I can know whether the user has tried it

I've tried to use restore purchases to get all orders
`[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]`

In the callback, I also succeeded in getting
However, there is a problem.

It will take 4-5 minutes to display the payment pop-up window of the app store if the purchase is called immediately
`[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment]`

Comment: Use `SKProductsRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the status of button on app open, you can keep the parse receipt data and original receipt data in local after purchase product.

Every time when user open application, you can check status from parsed receipt data and in background do receipt verification to get the latest receipt data and update local receipt data and parsed receipt data.

Comment: But users can change the apple store account to try again
Or application uninstallation

Comment: In that case you have to wait till not get the purchase data. You can get purchase using receipt verification or restoreCompletedTransactions.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't describe it clearly enough.
1. Users can change the apple store account to reuse the free trial,
2. When the app is uninstalled, I can't judge it correctly.
I want a more reliable way of judging in these situations.

Comment: If you want to give free trial only one time, then you have to keep any flag and store in keychain. If you get that flag, then you give product without free trial. If not get that flag from keychain, you can give free trial product.

Comment: This is really a good plan!
But what if the user has more than one device? For example, if the user's Apple Store account is subscribed on device A for trial, how can I judge that this account has been subscribed  for trial,On device B